# jquery fileupload - how to stop/pause upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I'm using BlueImp's jquery fileupload plugin and trying to figure out how to programatically stop the upload if other form fields haven't been provided. It doesn't seem that there is a method to stop the upload, other than destroy the instance completely, which isn't what i want to do. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        maxFileSize: 5000000,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        send: function(){
           // Validate text fields
           if (($('#name').text() == '') || ($('#division').text() == '') || ($('#location').text() == ''))
            alert('Please complete all of the fields');
            $('#fileupload').fileupload('destroy');
        }
    });
```

OK, figured this out - the "submit" event provides a callback which, if returns false, prevents the upload request from starting - which is what I want to do when validation fails

Comment: Can you provide some context?  If certain form fields are required, you should show error messages before you attempt to submit the form or perform the upload.  As far as I know, there is no way to stop an upload from JavaScript.